# button with simple mouse click event giving error 1046 ,compile-time constant: MouseEvent. not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a newbie ,

i am very new to the whole actionscript(using 3.0)

i have a button class and simply the main class

no other actionscript

button class name is graphic

and script in it is

```
    package{import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;public class graphic extends SimpleButton
    { 
     function graphic()
     {
     }
     function hamza(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
     trace("hamza")
     }
     graphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,hamza);
    } 
}
```

when i go to graphic linkage and enter graphic as class and click tick button
firstly it says
"The definition of this class was not found at ..path.."
But still the script is made which is

Here it says
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.

here i dont understand :(

Looks like it dosnt recognise the mouse eventlistener mabye
Please tell me the answer and also guide me on how to add this button on stage from main class(By addChild? but when i write in main class it not know what is button)

```
addChild(button);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import flash.events.*
```

You have to import more, in case you hit a "class definition not found" message. To find out where does the class belong in import tree, use [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html) and search from there.

Comment: Now it gives two more errrors

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.

Here i also think it does not know what is graphic(it is button to which i addeventlistener)

1120: Access of undefined property hamza.

these both errors are on line with addeventlistener

Comment: Remove that `graphic` before `addEventListener` totally, should do. Also, this line should be located within the braces of `function graphic(){...}`. You have to differ between a class and an instance read this up first. There is one class, but many instances of class, as say there's only one "bridge" class, an object is either a bridge or not a bridge, but many different instance bridges exist worldwide.

Comment: Also, if you want more help after resolving an initial issue, create another question and update it with all the details you can.

Comment: Very last thing
Can i only add in this constructor function (graphic) not other function ? as it gives errors why ? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```